# use multiple @reboot commands in crontab

Tags: crontab

I searched this website and Google but couldn't find it..
How can I execute two (or more) commands using `@reboot` ?

What I have now:

```
@reboot /root/website1/starter.sh
```

What I want:

```
@reboot /root/website1/starter.sh
@reboot /root/website2/starter.sh
```

Is this correct or should I solve it otherwise?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would probably be helpful to know what distro of Unix/Linux you're using. In the meantime, you might try putting both commands in a shell script and simply invoking that script from \@reboot.

Comment: "Is this correct?" *Does it work?*

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that is the correct approach.

You could also reduce it to a single line, as such:

```
@reboot /root/website1/starter.sh && /root/website2/starter.sh
```

Just keep in mind that the scripts will run consecutively (not concurrently), and the second script will only run if the first script/command exits successfully. If the second script should run regardless of the result of the previous script, separate the commands with a semi-colon instead of **&&**.

If you need the scripts to run in parallel, you should stick with your original approach (one command/script on each line).

> The double-ampersand (&&) can also be used in the "command" section to run multiple commands consecutively, but only if the previous command exits successfully. A string of commands joined by the double-ampersand will only get to the last command if all the previous commands are run successfully. If exit error-checking is not of a concern, string commands together, separated with a semi-colon (;)

[CronHowto - Crontab Example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Example)